# Can I safely delete old repository link from the git config file?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

When I first time installed git I used a wrong link to a repository.

I can see that in my config file found in .git folder in my Android Studio project has these settings:

```
ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
url = https://github.com/NrkSensors/Android.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch]
autosetuprebase = always
[branch "master"]
rebase = true
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "github"]
url = https://github.com/Muuddz/AndroidApp.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*
```

I want this removed **https://github.com/Muuddz/AndroidApp.git**
because this repository dosn't exist anymore. I can't find any ways in Android Studio to change it. What should I remove from the file to not corrupt anything?

Comment: @VKatz it worked by deleting this from line from the file

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change your `remote url` then you cant do it from terminal as follows

```
git remote set-url origin "your remote url"
```

**EDIT** : if you want to remove that wrong url, just execute following command

```
git remote remove github
```

Answer (score 0):

open your config file `vi .git/config` and delete line

`[remote "github"] url = https://github.com/Muuddz/AndroidApp.git fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/github/*`

then use

```
git remote set-url origin "https://github.com/NrkSensors/Android.git"
```

And world would be happy again!